# Python: Retrieve the current URL from the browser using bottle framework

Tags: python, url, urllib2, bottle

I am looking to retrieve the complete url of the browser using the bottle framework. Checked the documentation and found out the best way is to use the `geturl()` method. How should I go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bottle.request.url` returns the url. (It calls `geturl` behind the scenes.)

```
from bottle import Bottle, request

app = Bottle()

@app.route('/')
def root():
    return ['this url is: {}'.format(request.url)]

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

In action:

```
% python test.py &
Bottle v0.12.8 server starting up (using WSGIRefServer())...
Listening on http://0.0.0.0:8080/
Hit Ctrl-C to quit.

% curl 'http://localhost:8080/?hello'
this url is: http://localhost:8080/?hello
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that. In this case the return is a list or a string?

Comment: You're welcome! It returns a list of strings. See [this](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#generating-content) for an explanation.